# How do I make a non-blocking Promise which loops forever and does stuff in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, while-loop, promise

How do I make a non-blocking Promise which loops forever and does some stuff in node JS.

What is the working alternative to this?

```
let i = 0;
let p = new Promise(() => {
    while(true){i++;}
});
console.log("foo");
```

Comment: Don't, use the event loop.  That's the true benefit of node.js.  I don't know how to put this any other way.  Doing this will spin the CPU at 100% and be a waste.  The IO pattern is the core benefit of node.js.  Can you describe why you think this is the way you should go or maybe what your problem is in more detail?  There may be a better pattern that would fit your issue.

Comment: I can`t really explain my problem. I just want to know if there is a way to make a promise repeatedly do something without blocking.

Comment: a while loop will always be blocking, regardless of how many promise/callbacks/events you hide it behind. FInd another looping mechanism. What exactly are you trying to do repeatedly? Knowing the *what* will certainly help narrow down which tool would be the right one for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `setTimeout`

```
let i = 0;
function step() {
  i++;
  setTimeout(step, 0);
}
step();
console.log("foo");
```